# Iterate through multiple folders to compile all SASS to CSS in Gulp

Tags: gulp

I currently have a file structure like this

```
   projects
     sites
       site-example
            css
            scss
       site-second-example
            css
            scss
       site-third-example
            css
            scss
       ***
       site-fifty-example
            css
            scss
```

I'm trying to write a gulp task that I can run from the projects folder that will look inside the sites folder, and then go through each folder separately, look for any scss files, and then compile them to css.

I tried to follow this recipe but I must be messing it up somehow:
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md

**gulpfile.js**

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var merge = require('merge-stream');

    var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
    var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

    var output = './**/css';

    var sassOptions = {
      errLogToConsole: true,
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    };

    var scriptsPath = './sites';

    function getFolders(dir) {
        return fs.readdirSync(dir)
          .filter(function(file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
          });
    }

    gulp.task('sass', function() {

        var processors = [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 12 versions']
          })
        ];

       var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);

       var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
          return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/**/*.scss'))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(postcss(processors))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(output));
       });

       return merge(tasks);
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put a globstar `**` in your destination directory like this:

```
var output = './**/css';
```

That won't work, because `gulp.dest()` can't magically guess from context which directory you want your files to end up in.

You have to explicitly construct a destination directory for each `folder` returned from `getFolders()`, just as you do for `gulp.src()`:

```
var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
  var src = path.join(scriptsPath, folder, 'scss');
  var dst = path.join(scriptsPath, folder, 'css');
  return gulp.src(path.join(src, '**/*.scss'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
});
```

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what I was going for. Sorry it's my first day using Gulp, lol. Is Gulp capable of running a watch task similar to this that would only recompile the scss for changed sites? I have it a watch task working but it recompiles all 50+ sites if one site is changed.

Comment: Yeah, you could use something similar for `gulp.watch()`. Determine which `folder` the modified file is in, then construct the stream like above.